# How to detect other app's actions and data from our app?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app in which I want to capture events from other apps in the device. i.e. suppose an app's button is clicked then I want to get this click-event and modify it and perform some action accordingly. Is it possible? If yes then how?

Is there a firewall or Gateway in the Android system from where all the data going out of the device passes through? Is there a way to capture this data? Please help. Thanx in advance.

Comment: No, cannot be done.  Imagine the chaos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Fortunately, no, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Thanx dude. I just wanted to confirm.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you know how does Record My Call manages to start recording when the user receives a call and stops recording when the call is completed. Please check out my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014754/how-to-detect-activities-and-actions-in-other-app

Comment: @nighthawk24: Use a `PhoneStateListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not possible... unless the application you want to "spy" explicitly shares the data and/or the events.

The android way of exposing services, events and data is through [intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) and [broadcasts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: Thanx dude. I just wanted to confirm.